# RabbitMQ wont listen on port 5672

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rabbitmq

I've installed a Reddit Clone in an EC2 server and I am getting an error that says:

```
error connecting to amqp reddit @ localhost:5672 (IOError('Socket closed',))
```

As I checked using nmap on what ports were open and 5672, or the RabbitMQ port wasn't open. I tried restarting the rabbitmq-server already but to no success. I haven't touched any configuration files yet.

Is there anything I'm supposed to do before rabbitmq successfully listens to port 5672?

EDIT: I've solved my problem, I uninstalled RabbitMQ and installed it using the guide on the site http://www.theprogrammer.co.za/wordpress/2012/08/installing-rabbitmq-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/. Something might have been wrong in the installation script of reddit, that didnt work in my favor

Answer (score 1):

Try 15672 if you're on 3.0+ or 55672 if you're on an earlier version.